# Arpeggios on chords. Alternate or economy picking?

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar, arpeggios

As I'm tired from being able to make some arppegios on chords just with fingerstyle, I started praticing it with the pick (take musics GnR's Don't Cry or Civil War for example).
I ever did it with economy picking because it was easier. Make fingerstyle patterns with economy picking seems a lot easier than alternate.
But then I found a video on YouTube saying that it's better to train alternate picking with arppegios. Reference:

Is that right?
I mean, learning only with economy picking will stuck me in other situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use what works for you.

The way I was taught and the way I prefer is to start with alternate picking and use that as sort of your baseline. But once you learn alternate picking to the point of it being second nature there's no reason that can't move on to also using economy picking when appropriate.

As for *when* it's appropriate, that's up to you. Personally, I like the built-in rhythm to alternate picking. I play quite a bit of jazz and alternate picking gels better with that steady swinging rhythm. But I'll also use economy picking for selective passages (ex. sweeps across 3 or more strings).

There's no right way other than what works for you. But I would definitely learn both so that you can see the value of each before you decide.